# Open new tab or window using confirm() form

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, opera, window.open

I try to open some URL in new tab or window, but any Webkit based browser or Opera are block them. I trying many variants to make that, like `window.open()` etc. like this:

```
if(c<q){var l='url';
var g=$('<form action="'+l+'" style="display:none;" target="_blank"></form>')
.appendTo('.append').eq(0);
if(confirm('some text')){g[0].submit();}}
```

but any results...
- this code not blocked only on Firefox. How to create the right one?
Thank's for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).  Since it is handled in the DOM, it won't be blocked, and you get a lot more flexibility than native `confirm`  and popups.

Comment: I use this code, and  window are open. `$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Accept": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
     window.open(l,'width=300,height=450');
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });`